# setVisibility(View.Gone) work but the view still own the space

Tags: android, listview, visibility, invisible

I make a CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter.In it's getView() method , I use ViewHolder. And I set a clickListener with a TextView to set a view (call it `A`)gone and another view (call it `B`)visible , but when I click the TextView , the `A` GONE but it leave a space ,so the `B` cannot match the parent.
My code like

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    final ViewHolder viewHolder;
    if (convertView == null){
        convertView = mLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.customlayout,parent,false);
        viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
    }else {
        viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }
    viewHolder.textView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textview);
    viewHoler.a = (LinearLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.a);
    viewHoler.b = (LinearLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.b);
    viewHolder.textview.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (viewHolder.a.getVisibility() == View.GONE){
                viewHolder.b.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                viewHolder.a.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }else {
                viewHolder.a.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                viewHolder.b.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

        }
    });

    convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
    return convertView;
}
```

the customlayout code is

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="150dp">
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:src="@drawable/bg"/>
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"/>
        </RelativeLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/a"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:visibility="gone">
                <Button
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="button a"/>
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/b"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:visibility="visible">
                <Button
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="button b"/>
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

It should be show like this way when I click the textView 
[image]
[image]

but it always like another way below , just like the `A` view still take the space ,that like call `setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE)` or not `setVisibility(View.GONE)`
the `A` view is not appear because that although `B` view has disappeared but it still take the space 
[image]
[image]

Why will it behave like that? How should I do to solve it ?
Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Try with `wrap_content` on your `LinearLayout`s.

Like this -

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="150dp">
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:src="@drawable/bg"/>
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"/>
        </RelativeLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/a"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:visibility="gone">
                <Button
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="button a"/>
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/b"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:visibility="visible">
                <Button
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="button b"/>
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: See with Hierarchy Viewer to check what is taking space.